# Maximum amount of users in 2003 Active Directory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, user-management

Could you please number the maximum amount of users for 2003 Active Directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[About a billion RIDs per domain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574229.aspx) - thus, about a billion users can be created.

Note that deleting users doesn't make additional space; this limit is for the number of objects that exist or ever existed in the domain.

Comment: Also: [Technet - Active Directory Maximum Limits - Scalability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind this limit refers to *objects*, not just users, and that users are not the only things to create accounts in AD. Each computer that joins the domain is one less user that can be created, for example, as each computer creates an account for itself.